# Relation between projection matrix and linear span

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, regression, projection-matrices

Let $X$ be an $m \times n$ matrix. Define the orthogonal projection onto the column space of $X$ as

$$P(X):=X(X'X)^{-1}X'$$

Also, define the linear span of a set of $m\times 1$ column vectors of $X$ as $\mbox{span}(X)$.

I'm wondering what the relation between $P(X)$ and vector space $\mbox{span}(X)$ is. Can you help me with an intuitive explanation? Intuitive and easy interpretation would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not following some things. $X$ gives us $n$ vectors of $\mathbb{R}^m$. We define the projection on $\mathbb{R}^m$ ? and we define the projection over the span of the columns of $X$ ? So I suppose $n\leq m$ ? Another thing, I don't catch what means $X'$. What do you refer as a set of $mx1$ vectors, which vectors?

Comment: First, $X'$ is the transpose of $X$. It's assumed that $n \leq m$ holds. $m\times 1$ vectors refer to each $m\times 1$ columns of $X$.

Comment: $m$x$1$ columns ? $X$ doesn't have $n$ column vectors, and $n \leq m ?$

Comment: Consider EACH column of $X$. $X$ has $n$ number of $m\times 1$ vectors. And yes, $n\leq m$.

Comment: "mx1 vectors" ???. $X$ is mxn is impossible to get "mx1 vectors" whatever it means if $n \leq m$. Being $X$ mxn you have $n$ column vectors of $\mathbb{K}^m$ meaning that each of these vectors have $m$ components.

Comment: Then can you edit or suggest me a better way to put it? What I just meant is the dimension of each column is $m \times 1$. I didn't study mathematics rigorously and don't have much background.

Comment: mmm i think something like this: You originally have a space $V$ and the span of the columns of $X$ is a subspace of $V$. Now for every vector $v \in V$ you have the projection over $span(X)$. The usual notation is $P_X(v)$, the projection over the $span(X)$ of a vector $v$, making clear that $span(X)$ means the span of the vectors formed by its columns. As you have a mxn matrix each column has m components, "the dimension of each column vector" would be the dimension of the columns of the matrix, i.e, m. Now what I understand of your question is what is the relation between

Comment: between the projection itself and the subspace spanned by the column of $X$ but I am not sure about it

Comment: You need some conditions on $X$ for $P$ to even be defined: what properties must $X$ have for $X'X$ to be invertible?

Answer (score 0):

You have used the "regression" tag, so I assume that the context in linear regression.

The columns of design matrix $X$ form a vector space if there is no intercept in the model $Y= X\beta$, in a case of an intercept this is an affine space. The intuitive relation is that the hat matrix $H = X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ projects the $n$ dimensional response vectors $y$ into the space that is spanned by your explanatory variables. Namely, $Hy=\hat{y}$ gives you the "closest" vector that can be uniquely represented by a linear combination of the columns of $X$ (explanatory variables).